# What additional configuration needs to be done in order to enforce https using spring-security?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to secure my webapp such that all requests need to be made using https. I am using a Java based configuration, in particular I have a class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I have attempted to configure my security using the `@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {}` method as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650450/how-to-redirect-http-requests-to-https-using-spring-security-java-configuration) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538288/make-every-request-https-in-spring-security-3-2).

I've tried both of those and many variants of configuring the `HttpSecurity` object, as well as several variants of authentication. In almost all cases, I come up with the following issue:

```
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor : Error parsing HTTP request header
```

I tried doing some reading into this but a lot of the search results turned out to be dead ends for me. My assumption was that the solution that was hinted at in the two posts I referenced would give me roughly the correct answer, but is there any additional configuration I need to do before I can get https working? If so what is it, and if not, what am I missing here?

Below is my current configuration, which replicates the error described above (it is basically the default one plus the https channel):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Specify the authentication mechanisms that will allow user access to the site.
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ROLES_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

On the front end I am getting an `SSL Connection Error : Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.`

Comment: Can you show us the whole class?

Comment: Sure, edited the original post to include the whole configuration

Comment: try adding `super.configure(http);` as the first line in `configure`.

Comment: Your security config looks ok, Can we see your controller class? You sure everything in there is ok?

Comment: Application is configured to serve static resources on `/` and has one small test controller that returns "Hello world" on `account/hello`; could the fact that I have both static resources and java endpoints be a problem?

Comment: Do you have https configured on your server? If you only instruct spring security to always use Https but haven't setup your server for https it isn't going to work. As you are using Spring Boot (added the tag for you) this is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl).

Comment: This was what I was missing, if you answer I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.Deinum mentioned in comments, the difficulty was in the fact that I had not configured SSL in my `application.properties`. Creating one akin to the following:

```
server.port=9090
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password={password}
security.require-ssl=true
```

Resolved the issue.